# How to swap existing dataset used to populate datagridview with new dataset using VS2019 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dataset, visual-studio-2005

I've inherited a C# program written in 2012 using VS2005.  My PC doesn't have the original VS2005 or more importantly Microsoft.ACE.OLDDB.12.0 data provider which was used throughout to access Excel files used to populate data grids.

I don't want to rewrite the application as I only need to change a server path hard coded into the program and I don't have much time to complete it.

I've tried downloading the required file, but it is no longer available (understandable).

I have installed the ExcelDataReader and ExcelDataReader.DataSet packages and can create datasets.  I haven't been able to figure out how to swap the original datasets, which are empty as there is no provider, with my new ones.

The wizards all start from a database source, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Oledb provider still exists and kicking. Were you not able to find the installer? Top result from Google https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: I downloaded both the 2010 and 2016 versions.  Both wouldn't install, which may be caused by my company's network settings.  Anyway, I'd install the 64bit package and it would report I have 32bit already.  Then I'd install the 32bit and it would report I have 64bit.  Goofy.  That is why I tried the exceldatareader route.  I guess I'll contact my network admins.

Comment: 32bit and 64 bit versions are indeed mutually exclusive. Just uninstall the other and get the one appropriate for your binary. Bitness of your binary should match bitness of this lib.